# It is possible to delete file in a specific Android folder using Powershell?

Tags: android, powershell, file

I have to copy such file from a specific folder from my android device to a specific folder on my PC and after, delete this files from the device.

I can make the copy but I didn't find how to delete those files from the device.
Did someone has an advice to help me ?

Edit : I was sorry about how I want to do it. I did the copy using a powershell script. adb isn't a solution at the point.
I want to know if it is possible to do something like

```
Remove-Item -Path "Android/data/my-company-app/myfile"
```

Comment: You can handle this using ```adb``` command. https://superuser.com/questions/1251078/adb-command-for-powershell-windows

Comment: Sorry i wasn't very clear about what I really want. Using adb seems to be a good solution overall but not in my case.